# How to force Power BI service to use Local timezone

Tags: powerbi, microsoft-dynamics, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm currently exporting data from Dynamics. There are a lot of date fields I need to export. By default they are all UTC timezone. I want to report on New Zealand timezone. I tried to approaches in Power Query:

```
1) use DateTimeZone.ToLocal: =Table.TransformColumns(#"dataset", {{"**UTC Date**", **DateTimeZone.ToLocal**, type datetimezone}}) 

2) use a specific timezone ("en-NZ"): =Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"dataset", {{"UTC Date", type datetime}}, **"en-NZ"**)
```

Both approaches work OK in Power BI desktop report, However once I published to Power BI service and after several refreshes (initially it was NZ time), the time turn back to UTC time.

I don't want to create extra columns in DAX and really want to try use Power Query. Is there any way to work it out?

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue a while back and came up with the following solution.

You can simply use a combination of **RemoveZone and Addzone** power query function to achieve this. Example below shows how to get Indian Standard Time(IST = +5:30)

```
= DateTime.AddZone(DateTimeZone.RemoveZone(DateTimeZone.UtcNow()),5,30)
```

Note that I used `DateTimeZone.UtcNow()` to always get the Universal standard DateTime and then convert this to the Indian time. You can use your own timezone values

Add the above code in place of **DateTimeZone.ToLocal** in your code.

Documentation to [DateTime.AddZone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/datetime-addzone)

Comment: Thanks @Gangula. Do you think there is a way to handle daylight saving? NZ time is sometimes +13 hours to UTC, sometimes +12 hours to UTC (different year different dates)?

Comment: I was actually trying to do that but unfortunately there is no easy way. The possible way would be to use an API to extarct the list of times from a website like https://timezonedb.com/ and extract your timezone out of that. FYI, I have NOT tried the second approach.

Answer (score 0):

Power BI:

Use this Power Query function to convert times from UTC to Local Time, here its mountain time, but you can set to Whatever New Zealand Time is

```
let 
    ConvertDateColumnstoMountainTime = (sourcetable as table) as table => 
    let
        TargetColumnList = Table.ColumnsOfType(sourcetable, {type datetime, type nullable datetime, type datetimezone, type nullable datetimezone}),  
        AdjustTimeZones = Table.TransformColumns(sourcetable, List.Transform(TargetColumnList,
            (name) => {name, (date) => if date <> null
                then DateTime.From(DateTimeZone.RemoveZone(date) + #duration(0,CalculateUTCOffset(date,null),0,0))
                else null})),
        //Above returns type as text. Need it explicitly as Date. 
        AdjustColumnTypes = Table.TransformColumnTypes(AdjustTimeZones,List.Transform(TargetColumnList,
            (name) => {name, type datetime}))
    in AdjustColumnTypes

in ConvertDateColumnstoMountainTime
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting a datetimezone that respects daylight savings is a bit tricky sometimes. A solution I've used over and over again is the below function. You simply put in the offset for summertime and the one for wintertime, and it returns you the right time for your local zone.

```
(Summer_GMT_Offset as number, Winter_GMT_Offset as number) =>
let
    UTC_DateTimeZone = DateTimeZone.UtcNow(),
    UTC_Date = Date.From( UTC_DateTimeZone ),
    StartSummerTime = Date.StartOfWeek( #date( Date.Year( UTC_Date ) , 3 , 31 ), Day.Sunday ),
    StartWinterTime = Date.StartOfWeek( #date( Date.Year( UTC_Date ) , 10, 31 ), Day.Sunday ),
    UTC_Offset = if UTC_Date >= StartSummerTime and UTC_Date < StartWinterTime then Summer_GMT_Offset else Winter_GMT_Offset,
    CET_Timezone = DateTimeZone.SwitchZone( UTC_DateTimeZone, UTC_Offset)
in
    CET_Timezone
```

You can find it explained step by step through: https://gorilla.bi/power-query/last-refresh-datetime/

What's key is that DateTimeZone.UtcNow returns a fixed value (https://powerquery.how/datetimezone-utcnow/).

You then check whether the current date falls in the winter or summertime period and use that to adjust your Timezone-offset with DateTimeZone.SwitchZone (https://powerquery.how/datetimezone-switchzone/
)

Cheers,
Rick